# find and replace with a dictionary in a pandas column read from a json

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace characters and words in a pandas column with a dictionary read from a a json file.

specialChars.json 
{'è':'e', 
'µ':'u', 
'á':'a', 
'bar':'bat'}

```
with open('specialChars.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as handle:
    specialChars = json.loads(handle.read())

df
   col1
0  foo bar
1  fèe foo

desired result
   col1
0  foo bat
1  fee foo
```

I have tried

```
df[col1].replace(specialChars, regex=True)
```

Seems like it has something to do with reading the json because if i put it as a straight dictionary in the code it works?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: working on my python 3.7, pands 0.25. Did you read `df` from `csv`? If so, what encoding do you use?

Comment: encoded to utf-8

Comment: could you show the output of `print(specialChars)` and `type(specialChars)` ?

Comment: omg i am so stupid.... it was in a function and the function had the same name as the dict.

Answer (score 0):

solved. function had same name as dictionary.